# How fork process correctly under the Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have an API. API launchs a script, that may performs long time. about 90 seconds.
As you can suppose an API must to response immediately but the Flask isn't asynchronous.

I decide fork a process and run it backround.

First i try:

```
def start():
    pid1 = os.fork()
    if pid1 == 0:
        os.setsid()
        x = 30
        while x > 0:
            sleep(1)
            with open('/tmp/sleep.log', 'a') as fd:
                pid = str(os.getpid())
                print "child pid = ", pid 
                fd.write(pid  + ' PID \n')
            x -= 1
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        print os.getpid()
        while True:
            pass
start()
```

In this case it performs perfectly. A process is created, task is launched in backround then the child process is ended and the parent process still works.

Then i try move this code under the flask:

```
@app.route('/api/start', methods=['POST'])
def start():
    d1 = "DONE\n"
    pid1 = os.fork()
    if pid1 == 0:
        os.setsid()
        closer() #close all file descriptor who was inherited from parent
        x = 30
        while x > 0:
            sleep(1)
            with open('/tmp/sleep.log', 'a') as fd:
                pid = str(os.getpid())
                print "child pid = ", pid 
                fd.write(pid  + ' PID \n')
            x -= 1
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        print os.getpid()
    return d1
```

When i launched ps and saw this:

```
username    6158  0.0  0.4 106528 26192 ?        S    19:34   0:00 python -u /home/username/VCS/username/seek/lui/tcpdumper/dumper_api.py
username    6165  0.3  0.4 182876 26816 ?        Sl   19:34   0:05 /usr/bin/python /home/username/VCS/username/seek/lui/tcpdumper/dumper_api.py
username    6262  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   19:34   0:00 [python] <defunct>
```

My child process has state zombie.

The questions is why the process always launchs immediately as zombie under the flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, thank you Jonathon.
I will use your idea with queue.

I found out something that may help someone.

A parent process waits for their children, obviously.
But I thought it was sufficient to invoke os._exit(0) in order for the parent to obtain information about which of its children died.
It can be seen in strace's dump:

```
16059 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=16060, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```

But it isn't sufficient. To remove zombie processes you should set an exit handler for the parent process to initiate a reaping mechanism and then the OS will clean table of process.

To do it you should to use signal module like this:

```
def start():
    pid1 = os.fork()
    if pid1 == 0:
        os.setsid()
        x = 30
        while x > 0:
            sleep(1)
            with open('/tmp/sleep.log', 'a') as fd:
                pid = str(os.getpid())
                print "child pid = ", pid 
                fd.write(pid  + ' PID \n')
            x -= 1
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)
        print os.getpid()
        while True:
            pass
start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't `wait` on the process.

Zombies are processes that have "died" but are waiting for someone to reap them, by calling `wait` to retrieve their exit status.

Of course, you don't want to "wait" on the process, that's the whole problem.

If this is something your web application does routinely, I suggest going for a more robust solution. That would involve a daemon whose sole purpose is to process background tasks which the flask app will queue up for him. Flask could also query the status of the background jobs.

Answer (score 2):

A common architecture for long running jobs is to use a pool of background workers.

Add information about the job to a queue of some sort. Have a number of processes that are always running, reading jobs from the queue. They can take their time doing whatever they need to be doing - any slow operation basically.

Reply immediately to the request, maybe by HTTP 202, saying that the job has been queued.

I believe [Celery](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/) is popular in Flask.